# OpenGL - Access next 3 vertices in buffer from the vertex shader

Tags: c++, opengl, interpolation, vbo, vertex-shader

Im placing a bunch of square tiles around a world using 2 buffers fed from vector arrays, one for color and the other for position. The triangles vertex colors arent smooth as they dont interpolate between the two tris in the square. To combat this I wanted to set each fragments color individually, blending the colors of the vertices manually. I cannot substitute this process with premade textures either.

The issue Ive come across is passing the next 3 vertices position and location in the buffer into the vertex shader. Is there any easy way to do this?

Thanks and have a great day!

Comment: What do you mean by the vertex colors don't interpolate between the two tris? Can you add an image? There is no easy way of getting more than one vertex in the vertex shader, but I there may be another solution to your problem.

Comment: @JeremyLaumon http://puu.sh/ev0rj/2bf0c29a68.png This is a good example of the vertex lighting not interpolating between the tris in my tiles since its using barycentric filtering instead of bilinear as I want it to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add another set of attributes and  setup the `glVertexAttribPointer` to point into the vertex position buffer as well, but with an offset. Keep in mind, to add a bit of dummy padding to the end, so that when reaching the end of the array you don't access out of bounds. Also the `…_ADJACENCY` drawing modes are useful in this situation (if available).

Comment: Thank you @datenwolf! I had to do tons of fiddling around to get it to implement properly but mentioning the offset param put me in the right direction. Thank you very much